# This page isn’t working. HTTP ERROR 500. But when I refresh it works everytime

Tags: wordpress, http

I'm not sure how to replicate the error but every once in a while when I try to access the website i get this error and upon refreshing it immediately starts working again.
That's not the only issue, when I try to access sub pages other than the home page (like /products, /contact-us, etc) i get this error "Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."
I'm very inexperienced with all of this, especially wordpress websites so i'd appreciate any suggestions even if theyre basic.
Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a caching problem if it works on refreshing that page, but it’s hard to tell with so little information - a 500 server error just means “something went wrong” so it could be anything. Check your server logs for more information about what the error is.

Comment: im not sure whats causing it but the error log is not populating either

Comment: i turned on debug mode and even that just shows me a blank white screen with 0 information, its frustrating and i have no idea whats causing it, as soon as i refresh it everything is back to normal, but im more concerned about my costumers thinking the website is down when in reality it just needs a refresh